# Python 3 bytearray won't accept strings

Tags: python-3.x, binary-data

I have some serial protocol which uses first byte of the message to carry recipient's address. In Python 2 it worked but in 3 I get errors:

```
serial.write(bytes(chr(addr | 0x80)) + data)
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

`data` is a `bytearray` object here. How can I simply prefix it with the result of `addr | 0x80`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a solution that works in Python 2 & 3:

```
serial.write(bytearray([addr | 0x80]) + data)
```